# Is my controller for editing information about videos doing too much?

Tags: php, controller, zend-framework

My project uses Zend Framework 2.

I'm trying to determine if I am doing too much in my controller as a rule for my development. I have built my controllers like this for a while and haven't run into many problems but I wanted to get some feedback from this community.

This specific action handles a video management form that contains an image upload form.

Here is the action from my controller:

```
public function editAction() {
    $id = $this->params('id',null);
    $sl = $this->getServiceLocator();
    $form = $sl->get('AdminVideoForm');
    $image_form = $sl->get('VideoImageUploadForm');
    $image_form->setAttribute('action',$this->url()->fromRoute('admin/video/upload-image') . '?video_id=' . $id);
    $model = [
        'form' => $form,
        'image_form' => $image_form
    ];

    $current_video = $this->videoTable->fetchById($id);
    if(!$current_video) {
        $this->flashMessenger()->setNamespace('video-admin')->addMessage('Invalid Video ID');
        return $this->redirectToListing();
    }
    $model['id'] = $id;
    $model['video'] = $current_video;
    $form->bind($current_video);

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if($request->getQuery('returnTo')) {
        $model['returnTo'] = $request->getQuery('returnTo');
    }
    else {
        $model['returnTo'] = $this->url()->fromRoute('admin/video');
    }
    $form->setAttribute('action',$this->url()->fromRoute('admin/video/edit',['id' => $id]) . '?returnTo=' . rawurlencode($model['returnTo']));

    if($request->isPost()) {
        $form->setData($request->getPost());
        if($form->isValid()) {
            $this->videoTable->saveVideo($form->getData());
            return $this->redirectToListing();
        }
    }
    return $model;
}
```